# jQuery hide().fadeIn() adds style="display:block"

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, fadein

I'm using the following line of code to fade in the new row in the table:

```
$('table tr:last').after($(data.row).hide().fadeIn('fast'));
```

This row (tr) when faded in has the style of display:block assgined to it - and that screws things up in some of the browsers making the row narrower than the other rows.

Any suggestions on how to avoid this happening?

Here's what I'm getting :

```
<tr style="display: block;">
```

Comment: Works fine for me: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwWdu/). What is contained in `data.row`?

Comment: This seems to only be the case in IE7 and below. In all the other browsers I've tried, I get `display:table-row`.

Comment: another row '<tr>' - try it in Firefox and you'll see what I mean. I works fine in a few browsers, but in some it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could tag on : `.css('display', 'table-row')`  to ensure that ie 7 set's the display properly

```
$('table tr:last').after($(data.row).hide().fadeIn('fast').css('display', 'table-row'));
```

here's a fiddle showing it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/xS9rF/

Comment: this was bothering me tremendously. Great fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in some browers (firefox) there is something about hiding a tr before it's appended to the DOM. So another way, is to do hiding and effects after it's inserted:

```
$('table tr:last').after($(data.row));
$('table tr:last').hide().fadeIn('fast');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhRs2/